# Find the zeros of $\cos(z)+\sinh(iz)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, roots

As part of a worksheet I am currently going through, a question asks to

Find the zeros and their order of the following function: $\cos(z)+\sinh(iz)$

My attempt:

Rewrite $\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ and $\sinh(z)=\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2}$ and we can write $\sinh(iz)=i\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2}$

Then equating the two gives us $$e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=-(e^{iz}-e^{-iz}) \iff e^{iz}=-e^{iz}\iff e^{iz}=0$$

This, of course, cannot be true and so there is no solution i.e. there are no zeros of this equation.

I find it hard to believe that an exercise sheet would ask us to find the zeros and their order of a function that has none.

Is this simply an open shut case of "this function has no zeros" or is there something more complex that I am missing?

Comment: Simplify $\sinh(iz)$ to ... something. By the way, you did not shoaw an equation but an expression. Please, fix it.

Comment: Your final equation $e^{iz} = e^{-iz}$ does have solutions! ($z=k\pi, k\in\mathbb Z)$. You made an error in the derivation, it should be $e^{iz}=0$ instead, which doesn't has  a solution in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry it should be $e^{iz}=-e^{iz} \iff 2e^{iz}=0 \iff e^{iz}=0$. I put the negative sign in the wrong place, I will change this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\sinh(iz)=i\sin z$ and therefore that$$\cos z+\sinh(iz)=0\iff\cos z+i\sin z=0\iff e^{iz}=0.$$So, yes, there are no roots.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.

$$\sinh(iz) = i\sin(z)$$

Comment: @User Who cares. Many answers on MSE are given as HINTS. I don't have to work the complete answer; the OP has to run his hands too. I can help with hints as I did, especially when the questions are really silly.